# php htmlentities on <code></code> only!

Tags: php, html, implode

I want to run htmlentities() only on the contents within <code> things to strip </code>

I Wrote a function that takes a string and finds the content in between <code> </code>

`function parse_code($string) {`

```
        // test the string and find contents with <code></code>
        preg_match('@<code>(.*?)</code>@s', $string, $matches);

            // return the match if it succeeded
            if($matches) {
                return $matches[1];
            }else {
                return false;
            }
    }
```

However I need some help with a function that will will actually run htmlentities(); on the contents within  <code> </code> and then implode() it all back together.  For example lets say we have the string below.

```
<div class="myclass" rel="stuff"> things in here </div>
<code> only run htmlentites() here so strip out things like < > " ' & </code>
<div> things in here </div>
```

Once again, The function would need to keep all contents of the string the same but only modify and run htmlentities() on the contents of <code> </code>

Comment: I suggest you read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify this with using a custom callback function:

```
$html = preg_replace_callback(
     "@  (?<= <code>)  .*?  (?= </code>)  @six",
     "htmlentities_cb", $html
);

function htmlentities_cb($matches) {
    return htmlentities($matches[0], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
}
```

The syntax for matching the enclosing code tags is called [lookbehind and lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It simplifies the callback and avoids implode() later, because the assertion matches itself do not become part of $matches[0]. While @six is for case-insensitve tag matches and allows whitespace in the regex to make it more readable.

Comment: I'm going to test this out, and if it worked, I love you I love you I love you.

Comment: @kr1zmo: Tested it, but better give it a try with your code. Also don't forget the extra htmlentities parameters (like I did) for better security.

Comment: so how exactly would I run this if I have my string $query = ''; that has all the html and code tag.

Comment: @kr1zmo: Just use `$query` in place of `$html =` and `, $html` in the preg_replace invocation.